# "replacement has 2 rows, data has 114591" with foreach and doparallel

Tags: r, foreach, doparallel

I'm tring to handle some large data with foreach and doparallel, and I got this error:

> Error in { : task 2 failed - "replacement has 2 rows, data has 114591"
> Calls: %dopar% ->  Execution halted

The original code is:

```
data <-read.csv("testdata.csv")
times <- subset(data, timestep == 50)
id_particle <- as.numeric(times$Particle_ID)
times$velo_flu <- 0

cl<-makeCluster(detectCores())
registerDoParallel(cl)

foreach(i = id_particle, .combine='rbind') %dopar% {
  temp <- data.frame()
  temp <- subset(data, Particle_ID == i)
  times$velo_flu[which(times$Particle_ID == i)] <- sd(temp$abs_velocity)
  }

   
stopImplicitCluster()    
write.csv(times,file = "output.csv")
```

I have read other answers but still cannot solve my problem.

Comment: You'll need to provide some test data that demonstrates the problem, using for example `data <- data.frame(abs_velocity=rnorm(1e3), Particle_ID = sample(1:10, 1e3, T), timestep = 1:50)` the code appears to work (albeit slowly)

Comment: If you provide a reproducible part of your daraset, it would be easier to solve your issue.(dput format prefered)